# Django admin, hide a model

Tags: django, django-admin

At the root page of the admin site where registered models appear, I want to hide several models that are registered to the Django admin.

If I directly unregister those, I am not able to add new records as the add new symbol "+" dissapears.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Based on [x0nix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431727/django-admin-hide-a-model/2774872#2774872) I did some experiments. It seems like returning an empty dict from `get_model_perms` excludes the model from index.html, whilst still allowing you to edit instances directly.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        """
        Return empty perms dict thus hiding the model from admin index.
        """
        return {}

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Agreed. Only that's a problem when I don't want to change the code. What I mean is, I have a base app that I want to keep clean from dependencies on other apps. I keep these dependencies in a derived project-specific app. Now I want the admin interface to only show the derived app, not the base app. Django requires the base app to be listed in settings/INSTALLED_APPS for the derived app to work. Obviously, the base app shouldn't show, but at the same time I don't want to keep it unmodified and reusable.See [here]([se]/questions/13923968/).

Comment: A shorter way: `get_model_perms = lambda self, req: {}`

Comment: What if I want to hide a model form a certain userAdmin ?

Comment: Be careful with this solution - even though the link is disappears, user can jump to the object itself like this: /admin/main/comment/2333/change/

Answer (score 53):

**For Django 1.8 and above**

Since Django 1.8, `ModelAdmin` has got a new method called [`has_module_permission()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_module_permission) which is responsible for displaying a model in admin index.

To hide a model from admin index, just create this method in your `ModelAdmin` class and return `False`. Example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Comment: Unfortunately `has_module_permission` affects the whole app and not just the one model. So adding this to a model in the app causes a 403 Forbidden in the app model list (/admin/app_label/). See [django/contrib/admin/sites.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/255fb992845e987ef36e3d721a77747a0b2df620/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L401).

Comment: @Fabian I think that's a bug. I asked this on Django's IRC channel, and some people there agree that this behaviour is undesired.

Comment: @Fabian Assuming the admin index page still links to _/admin/_ it is possible to circumvent that bug by something like `return request.path!='/admin/'`. Unfortunately that reenables those models in the app model list.

Comment: I had opened a [ticket here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26954) for this bug. This has been [fixed here](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6999). It should be included in the next release, hopefully.

Comment: In Django 1.11 the deep link still works but the entity is not listed on the main admin screen

Comment: Still working on Django 4.0.5!

Answer (score 25):

Got the same problem, here what I came up with.

Like in previous solution - copy index.html from django to your /admin/index.html and modify it like this:

```
{% for model in app.models %}
    {% if not model.perms.list_hide %}
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And create ModelAdmin subclass:

```
class HiddenModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_model_perms(self, *args, **kwargs):
        perms = admin.ModelAdmin.get_model_perms(self, *args, **kwargs)
        perms['list_hide'] = True
        return perms
```

Now any model registered with HiddenModelAdmin subclass won't show up in admin list, but will be available via "plus" symbol in detail:

```
class MyModelAdmin(HiddenModelAdmin):
    ...

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: This still works, except I had to edit app_list.html because the index I had did not have the loop inside.
Also you can add a bit of javascript to hide the empty app title if the list is empty after list_hide.

Answer (score 3):

As of Django **1.8.18**, `has_module_permission()` still has issue. So, in our case we used also the `get_model_perms()`. Likewise, we need to hide the model for specific user only, but the `superuser` should be able to access its index entry.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return {}
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_model_perms(request)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly solution: [override](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) admin index template i.e. copy index.html from django to your /admin/index.html and add something like this:

```
{% for for model in app.models %}
    {% ifnotequal model.name "NameOfModelToHide" %}
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative building on top x0nix's answer, and only if you are happy hiding the the rows with jquery.

Copy pasting from the other answer the part that I reused

```
class HiddenModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def get_model_perms(self, *args, **kwargs):
    perms = admin.ModelAdmin.get_model_perms(self, *args, **kwargs)
    perms['list_hide'] = True
    return perms

class MyModelAdmin(HiddenModelAdmin):
...

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Then install [django-jquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jquery) and then add the following block in your `/admin/index.html` template:

```
{% extends "admin:admin/index.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
    {% if app_list %}
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          {% for app in app_list %}
            {% for model in app.models %}
                {% if model.perms.list_hide %}
                    $('div.app-{{ app.app_label }}').find('tr.model-{{ model.object_name|lower }}').hide();
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        });
     </script>
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

You don't need to copy paste the whole template, just extend it and override the `extrahead` block. You'll need [django-apptemplates](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-apptemplates/) for the above to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had lots of model admins to register and hide, if you want a more DRY solution, this worked for me (Django 1.10, Python 3.5)

```
# admin.py

def register_hidden_models(*model_names):
    for m in model_names:
        ma = type(
            str(m)+'Admin',
            (admin.ModelAdmin,),
            {
                'get_model_perms': lambda self, request: {}
            })
        admin.site.register(m, ma)

register_hidden_models(MyModel1, MyModel2, MyModel3)
```

I guess you could roll it into a utility class if you want to re-use it across apps.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.2 has new if-statements, meaning that the desired feature could be obtained only by overwriting admin/index.html

```
{% if model.name not in "Name of hidden model; Name of other hidden model" %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

This is a bad solution, because it doesn't care about multi-language admins. You could of course add the names of models in all of the supported languages. It's a good solution because it doesn't overwrite more than one aspect of core Django functions.

But before changing anything, I think people should think about this...

Essentially the problem is related to having models that one does not wish to use for more than adding an option to a drop-down once in a while. It could effectively be worked around by creating a set of permissions for "not so advanced" users that panic when there are too many models. In case changes in the particular models are required, one can simply log in with the "advanced account".