# Overriding admin templates depending on Django version

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

Is there any way to override admin templates with different files depending on Django version?

I've copied `admin/index.hml` from Django admin templates, to achieve this: [Django admin, hide a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431727/django-admin-hide-a-model), but there are changes in that template in different versions of Django, and sometimes the page breaks (specially with the deprecation of `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` in Django 1.4)

I want to install my site in many servers with different versions of Django, but using just one unified code that notices the version automatically. Is that possible?

I've checked [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates), but I haven't found anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ModelAdmin` class has various template settings that you can specify in subclasses. In Django 1.3 these are (at `django.contrib.admin.options`, line 271):

```
add_form_template = None
change_form_template = None
change_list_template = None
delete_confirmation_template = None
delete_selected_confirmation_template = None
object_history_template = None
```

Similarly, `AdminSite` has various template settings (at `django.contrib.admin.sites`, line 35):

```
index_template = None
app_index_template = None
login_template = None
logout_template = None
password_change_template = None
password_change_done_template = None
```

You can override these for subclasses or specify them in a central location in your code (e.g., a `__init__.py` file). For example:

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
AdminSite.index_template = '...'
```

You can then vary the templates based on the current Django version. You may need to check what the code looks like in earlier Django versions as I haven't checked if all these variables are present in earlier Django admin code.