# Django Admin: Remove Table from main page

Tags: django

How do I remove or hide a link to a table from the main admin page without unregistering it? I only want the table to be editable/addable by clicking on a link next the foreign key. I've looked through the admin docs and can't find anything, but this should be a commonly used feature.

Comment: The answers to this question should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431727/django-admin-hide-a-model

Comment: awesome. Thank you so much. How do I handle this question now? should I delete it since it is a repeat?