# Django raw_id_fields widget not showing search icon

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following code in my admin.py:

```
class UserManagedGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MembershipInline]
    search_fields = ('name', 'leader__username', )
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'leader', )
    filter_horizontal = ('permissions', )
    raw_id_fields = ('leader', )

admin.site.register(UserManagedGroup, UserManagedGroupAdmin)
```

The magnifying glass icon for searching doesn't appear in the admin page.

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see it's showing the unicode method of the model instead of the search icon I want.

Field `'leader'` is a `ForeignKey` to `User`.

Could it be that django disables the search for `ForeignKeys` to `User` for security reasons, or am I doing something wrong?

The widget would be perfect for choosing users... I mean, I can't leave a huge select there with every user of my site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've found the problem thanks to [this message](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/Yg1PtV_D-ME) in django-users.

I had to register in the admin the model to which the `ForeignKey` points to.

The search doesn't work without that.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Just to clarify for the example given in the question. The asker doesn't have `User` registered in the admin so the admin doesn't recognize it. The manifestation of that is that the spyglass icon doesn't show.

Answer (score 3):

In the `admin.py` file add:

```
admin.site.register(YourModel)
```

This did the trick, Where YourModel is the model to be displayed with the magnifying glass

Answer (score 3):

Hi encounter the same issue but reason's a bit different.

To integrate the User and UserGroup with another app's admin (e.g. `some_app`)

I added below code to `some_app/admin.py`

```
class ProxyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = User._meta.verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = User._meta.verbose_name_plural


class ProxyGroup(Group):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = Group._meta.verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = Group._meta.verbose_name_plural

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(ProxyGroup)
admin.site.register(ProxyUser, UserAdmin)
```

I think the `unregister(...)` will affect the other app's admin Globally!

That's another cause of missing search icon.

Comment: If I'm in this situation, but I want the chooser to appear for me still? Because I do register an Admin which is a combined Admin for the Django `User` class plus my customized `UserProfile` class.

Comment: I gonna register a separate Admin for the `UserProfile` and will try to hide it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431727/django-admin-hide-a-model