# Hide editable model from index page in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there a way to allow editing of a table through the Django admin site, but not display the model on the index page?

Comment: Are you also locking down permissions? If not, all someone has to do is guess the url from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed this question asked previously.  This answer worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4871511/3422594